# Integrating OpenCPPCoverage with Sonarqube

Tags: c++, windows, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage

How can I integrate OpenCppCoverage with sonarqube? I cannot find any way to have OpenCppCoverage produce files that are compatible with SonarQube. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCppCoverage supports the usage of plugins that can be used to generate coverage report of your desired format. SonarQube supports a generic format specified in their docs. [OCCSonarQube](https://github.com/KevinLussier/OCCSonarQube) is one such plugin which can generate reports that can be parsed by SonarQube. But the plugin may not work if your scanner expects case-sensitive paths for your source files. You can use the plugin by fixing that issue. But no, it is not possible to produce files that are compatible with SonarQube solely using OpenCppCoverage